# MySQL Routine Not Working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a routine I am attempting to create on mysql server.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE `Create.Site`( SrvID BIGINT(20), sType BIGINT(20),
              sParent BIGINT(20), sName VARCHAR(150),
              sDesc LONGTEXT, sSetts LONGTEXT )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE ID BIGINT(20);
        /* Error Handling */
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
            BEGIN
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
                                            @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO,
                                            @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno,
                                         " (", @sqlstate, "): ",
                                         @text);
                SELECT @full_error;
                ROLLBACK;
            END;
        COMMIT;

        START TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO `Sites`
                (`serverID`, `siteType`, `siteParent`)
            VALUES
                (SrvID, sType, sParent);
            SET ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            INSERT INTO `Common`
                (`attachWhich`, `attachID`, `commName`, `commSettings`)
            VALUES
                (2, ID, sName, sDesc);
        COMMIT;

    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

While it creates and even executes without error, there is no data created.   There is nothing in the mysql error log either.  I have tried changing all names (columns/tables/routine)

Also changed the `SELECT @full_error;` to `SELECT @full_error INTO OUTFILE '/var/log/mysql/create-site-error.txt';` and there is nothing created...

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I get this to work?

**MySQL:** Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.23-MariaDB

Comment: Well, for troubleshooting purposes, you could remove the rollback; to see if the data sticks.  Of course, you would want to either make a copy of the database to run this on.  If it is hitting the rollback, but not entering log info, there is obviously a problem with the way the log is being written.  So, instead you could try to insert data into a temp table.

Comment: tried that too.. still nothing.   It's the mysql user/group that writes to logs correct?

Comment: hmmm not sure.  I would check your users DB/Table permissions though.  Not sure about MariaDB, but in MySQL the permissions are different if you are accessing remotely vs from the local host.

Comment: All localhost.   I'm doing this all through phpmyadmin tho, as well as logged in as highest `root` account

Comment: I even removed all the transaction and error checking stuff from the script.  Still nothing

Comment: If you run the core query of the procedure outside of the query, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Create.Site` worries me.  Could you change it to `Create_Site` and change the `CALL`.  What is the name of the database that you are applying it to.

Did you check for errors after the `CALL`?

Comment: Sorry it's been awhile mate... been getting slammed with work.
Yeah, no errors after the `CALL`, also changed the name like you show, still the same.... nothing entered, no errors anywhere... not even in `syslog`

Comment: just for s*&ts & giggles I manually set the parameters, and ran the `CALL`, this time I got an error: `#1436 - Thread stack overrun:  7520 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.`   I have no idea what it means, or how to fix it tho...   Is that something I can set in the `mysql.ini`?

Comment: found it... time to test... I'll let you know

Comment: `thread_stack` is usually 196608 or 262144.  Any more than that will be a waste of RAM.

Comment: Aye.  default was 128K, I just set it to 256K, back to the original issue... no errors anywhere, no data inserted

Comment: Got it fixed., even works with the original code.   It was failing on relationships